# Convert markdown italics and boldface to latex

Tags: windows, r, latex, markdown

I want to be able to convert markdown italics and boldface to latex versions on the fly (i.e., give a text string(s) return a text string(s)).  I thought easy.  Wrong! (Which it still may be).  See the sill buisness and error I tried at the bottom.

**What I have (note the starting asterisk that's been escaped as in markdown):**

```
x <- "\\*note: I *like* chocolate **milk** too ***much***!"
```

**What I would like:**

```
"*note: I \\emph{like} chocolate \\textbf{milk} too \\textbf{\\emph{much}}!"
```

I'm not attached to regex but would prefer a base solution (though not essential).

**Silly business:**

```
helper <- function(ins, outs, x) {
    gsub(paste0(ins[1], ".+?", ins[2]), paste0(outs[1], ".+?", outs[2]), x)
}

helper(rep("***", 2), c("\\textbf{\\emph{", "}}"), x)

Error in gsub(paste0(ins[1], ".+?", ins[2]), paste0(outs[1], ".+?", outs[2]),  : 
  invalid regular expression '***.+?***', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'
```

I have [this toy](https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/R/wheresPandoc.R) that Ananda Mahto helped me make if it's helpful. You could access it from reports via `wheresPandoc <- reports:::wheresPandoc`

**EDIT** Per Ben's comments I tried:

```
action <- paste0(" echo ", x, " | ", wheresPandoc(), " -t latex ") 
system(action)

*note: I *like* chocolate **milk** too ***much***! | C:\PROGRA~2\Pandoc\bin\pandoc.exe -t latex
```

**EDIT2** Per Dason's comments I tried:

```
out <- paste("echo", shQuote(x), "|", wheresPandoc(), " -t latex"); system(out)
system(out, intern = T)

> system(out, intern = T)
\*note: I *like* chocolate **milk** too ***much***! | C:\PROGRA~2\Pandoc\bin\pandoc.exe -t latex
```

Comment: don't know the context, but: any chance of using pandoc to render Markdown to LaTeX? ` echo '\*note: I *like* chocolate **milk** too ***much***!' | pandoc -t latex`

Comment: Possible I thought about this (possibly using `pander`) but it seemed like over kill for converting a string here or there (like a bazooka for a mosquito).  That may be the route to go. Plus it would require en external file and read back in (I think but could be wrong).

Comment: @TylerRinker You don't need to write to an external file - you just need to use the command line correctly.

Comment: `out <- paste("echo", shQuote(x), "| pandoc -t latex"); ans <- system(out, intern = T)`

Comment: `pander` has a function `Pandoc.convert` -- for the life of me I can't work out how to set it not return a complete latex document.

Comment: I'm on a windows machine so this could be making it difficult.  PS the output of `out` above in the actual windows command line turns out as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noting I am working on windows and from `?system`

> This means that redirection, pipes, DOS internal commands, ... cannot be used

and the note from `?system2`

> ### Note
>
> system2 is a more portable and flexible interface than system,
>   introduced in R 2.12.0. It allows redirection of output without
>   needing to invoke a shell on Windows, a portable way to set
>   environment variables for the execution of command, and finer control
>   over the redirection of stdout and stderr. Conversely, system (and
>   shell on Windows) allows the invocation of arbitrary command lines.
>   Using `system2`

```
system2('pandoc', '-t latex', input = '**em**', stdout = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm including work from this in the reports package and want to attribute authorship to you.  I will use mnel of stackoverflow.com unless you email me and let me know the proper name to use.

Comment: Sorry I figured you'd go find the reports package ; Didn't want to grandstand :)  tyler.rinker@gmail.com

Comment: @TylerRinker -- I meant in your inbox -- I could find your email :)

Comment: Oh :)  Gottcha (insert dimwitted comment here).

Answer (score 4):

The lack of pipes on Windows made this tricky, but you can get around it using `input` to provide the `stdin`:

```
> x = system("pandoc -t latex", intern=TRUE, input="\\*note: I *like* chocolate **milk** too ***much***!")
> x
[1] "*note: I \\emph{like} chocolate \\textbf{milk} too \\textbf{\\emph{much}}!"
```

Comment: Works well but I liked the `system2` just a bit more.  Thank you for you pushing the answer forward.